# Maven like local repository with Gradle

Tags: gradle

It is common use case to have multiple standalone projects which are related to each other. For example some common utilities library. With Maven, you can just install your modified dependency locally so it is used when building your dependent project. I always took this funtionality for granted (IDEs support this as well).

But with Gradle i have not found any similiar functionallity. I don´t want to have local Maven installation (what´s the point of Gradle then) just to be able to install artifacts locally. Also I don´t want to depend on CI, since during development programmers like to iterate until they are happy with API. There would be many useless commits just to compile and install it in our Nexus.

Is there any best practise how to manage local development or related projects which do not share common root?

Comment: I believe what you have taken for granted is actually something violating what Maven aimed to provide: Reproducible Build.  Anyway, Gradle equivalent of Maven local repo, in some extends, is the cache under `.gradle ` in your local home.

Comment: I understand your point, but as far as local development goes having to use CI for iterative work would be performance and repository nightmare. From my understanding, Gradle cache is not the solution. It is intended as cache only and artifacts should not be installed into it.

Comment: I don't understand your point though.  Anyway, why not just add a repository which is a local directory in your gradle config then? or simply add `mavenLocal()` as one of your repositories

Comment: I am basically just looking for best practice for local development of related projects. If you insist local repository approach is flawed in principle, what is your way of work then? I have searched for some guides with Gradle and best I could find is to use CI and your company repository. But this seems like overkill for reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Maven local is resolved using Ant task and you have to set .m2/settings.xml with correct repository path. So you have one build system sort of depending on another on the same machine. Also Gradle partially adressed this with Composite builds. But they are not as transitive.

Comment: I think that [composite builds](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-composite-builds) are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree, they mostly are. But you still have to create "composite build project" per user and his FS, per project. But its closest to what I have in mind. If composite builds could be automated globally, ideally independent of local FS structure, they would be holy grail for me.

Comment: At the end of the day, a composite build can be expressed in groovy logic. For instance you could drive the composite by which subfolders are in a given root folder etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can publish/reference jars in `mavenLocal()` without having `Maven` installed (it's just a directory which gradle knows how to read/write to)

Secondly, Gradle will create a [PublishToMavenLocal](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/tasks/PublishToMavenLocal.html) task for every [MavenPublication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) in your build so you can invoke these to install jars in `%USER_HOME%/.m2`

And Thirdly... forget my first and second points. If you don't want to use `mavenLocal()` you can use the new [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) feature added in Gradle 3.1. In my opinion this feature is far better than mavenLocal since snapshot jars will never be fetched remotely after the expiry period and instead the local sources will always be used. This has tripped me up many times with maven where locally installed snapshot jars have expired

Comment: I have read on Gradle forum that mavenLocal() resolution is implemented by Ant task in which logic for repository lookup is hardcoded and only way to change its location is using .m2/settings.xml. Anyway I agree that composite builds look like the best option so far.